# How make this code shorter and accurate this code is just a basic code how to make it more efficient

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
double a, pi = 3.14, r, c, d, h;
printf("Program to calculate area of circle and volume of cylinder in cm^2 and cm^3 respectively\n");
printf("select what you want to find?\n1.Area of circle\n2.Volume of cylinder\n");
scanf("%lf", &c);
if (c == 1)
{
    printf("Select unit\n1.CM\n2.Meter\n ");
    scanf("%lf", &d);
    if (d == 1)
    {
        printf("enter radius in cm\n");
        scanf("%lf", &r);
        a =pi * r * r;
        printf("the area of circle is \n%lf cm^2", a);
    }
    if (d == 2)
    {
        printf("enter radius in meter\n");
        scanf("%lf", &r);
        a = pi *r * r*10000;
        printf("the are of circle is \n%lf cm^3", a);
    }
}
else
{
    if (c == 2)
    {
        printf("select unit\n1.cm\n2.meter\n");
        scanf("%lf", &d);
    }
    if (d == 1)
    {
        printf("enter radius in cm\n");
        scanf("%lf", &r);
        printf("enter height in cm\n");
        scanf("%lf", &h);
        a = pi*r * r * h;
        printf("the volume of cylinder is\n%lf cm^3", a);
    }
    if (d == 2)
    {
        printf("enter radius in meter \n");
        scanf("%lf", &r);
        printf("enter the height of cylinder in meter \n");
        scanf("%lf",&h);
        a = pi *r * r * h*1000000;
        printf("the volume of cylinder is\n%lf cm^3", a);
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make this code more accurate and short please also explain the concepts too about the More efficient code this code is just a basic code tell me about how to make this code advanced and meaningful also if you have some advice about how to c language code please give because i just started learning c language if there is any error please tell me that as well.

Comment: change `d` to an `int` - and check the return from `scanf`

Comment: You have divided an area by `100` for the units conversion. Perhaps you should be dividing by `1000` for a volume, but both are wrong to convert **cm** to **m**, where 100 is the *linear* ratio.

Comment: Ditto with `c`.

Comment: Don't post complete code. Narrow it down to a [mre]

Comment: You're missing a closing brace in the first `if`.  That's why it's not calculating volume; it never gets to the correct `else`.  The `else` you think is executing is tied to the third `if`.

Comment: Fixed your indentation, which instantly shows the problem

Comment: Aside: `pi = 3.14` is fairly approximate.  Maybe use [3.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill).  I recommend 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 and let the compiler use a close `float` value.

Comment: lol @chux-ReinstateMonica ... maybe [3.876](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmgCgzjlWO4) instead

Comment: @pmg, better to discuss `pi`  [tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_Day).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I recommend using `PI = acos(-1)`.

Comment: @ganjaam Pedantically, with OP's `float`, better as `PI = acosf(-1)`.

Comment: just forget `float` and use `double` ... forever...

Comment: @ganjaam - Better still `#include <math.h` then use `M_PI` (or `#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846`)

Comment: Exploring and understanding control flow for if-else is expected. You have messed up with the if-else blocks indentation. Please verify the logical blocks. Also, no input taken for the height variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation for the logical if-else block is misplaced.Also no input was taken for height variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    float a, pi = 3.14, r, c, d, h;
    printf("Program to calculate area of circle and volume of cylinder \n");
    printf("select what you want to find?\n1.Area of circle\n2.Volume of cylinder\n");
    scanf("%f", &c);
    if (c == 1)
    {
        printf("Select unit\n1.CM\n2.Meter\n ");
        scanf("%f", &d);
        if (d == 1)
        {
            printf("enter radius in cm\n");
            scanf("%f", &r);
            a = (pi * r * r) / 100;
            printf("the area of circle is \n%f cm", a);
        }
        if (d == 2)
        {
            printf("enter radius in meter\n");
            scanf("%f", &r);
            a = pi * r * r;
            printf("the are of circle is \n%f meter", a);
        }
    }
    else #This block is indented.
    {
        if (c == 2)
        {
            printf("select unit\n1.cm\n2.meter\n");
            scanf("%f", &d);
        }
        if (d == 1)
        {
            printf("enter radius in cm\n");
            scanf("%f", &r);
            printf("enter height in cm\n");
            scanf("%f", &h);
            a = (pi * r * r * h) / 100;
            printf("the volume of cylinder is\n%f cm", a);
        }
        if (d == 2)
        {
            printf("enter radius in meter \n");
            scanf("%f", &r);
            printf("enter the height of cylinder in meter \n");
            scanf("%f", &h); #This is added
            a = pi * r * r * h;
            printf("the volume of cylinder is\n%f meter", a);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```